# SharePoint 2010 error 0x80131904 after uploading large amount of files

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, sharepoint-2010

After dragging and dropping amount of documents to the server (roughly about 6gbs) using window explore (not uploading through the SharePoint site), I'm not able to delete files, create sites, or even edit.. nothing! However, I can browse through the site like nothing happen. How can I deleted the files I recently uploaded?

When I do so, I'm receiving this message.....

I try setting the database is full and it's not, so I'm not sure what to do?
[image: DB does not look full to me]

While I tried deleting the site...
[image]

======================Error======================================

Server Error in '/' Application.

```
Error: 0x80131904
```

**Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details:**

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 0x80131904

**Source Error:**

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

**Stack Trace:**

```
[COMException (0x80131904): <nativehr>0x80131904</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>]
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.SetGhostedFile(String setupPath, Byte setupPathVersion, Int32 iVersion, Guid& pguidListId, Guid& pguidDocId, Int32 lDoclibRowId, Int32 iAuthorId, String authorLogin, String serverRelativeUrl, String targetUrlWebRelative, Boolean isInDocLib, Boolean isMigration, Boolean isPublishing, Object varProperties) +0
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.SetGhostedFile(String setupPath, Byte setupPathVersion, Int32 iVersion, Guid& pguidListId, Guid& pguidDocId, Int32 lDoclibRowId, Int32 iAuthorId, String authorLogin, String serverRelativeUrl, String targetUrlWebRelative, Boolean isInDocLib, Boolean isMigration, Boolean isPublishing, Object varProperties) +268
```

**[SPException]**

```
 Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx) +27713762
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.SetGhostedFile(String setupPath, Byte setupPathVersion, Int32 iVersion, Guid& pguidListId, Guid& pguidDocId, Int32 lDoclibRowId, Int32 iAuthorId, String authorLogin, String serverRelativeUrl, String targetUrlWebRelative, Boolean isInDocLib, Boolean isMigration, Boolean isPublishing, Object varProperties) +28110127
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileCollection.AddGhosted(String sourceFilePath, String targetFilePath, Boolean bIsPublishing) +26702334
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.CreateNewWikiPage(SPList wikiList, String url) +109
   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.CreateWebPage.SubmitBtn_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) +715
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +115
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +140
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +29
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2981
```

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5456; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5456

Comment: Ahh, reminds me of the days when I had to connect WinDbg to SharePoint 2007 sites, just to figure out what an error message in the UI actually meant. Often you would see a useless error message in the UI which was hiding the more useful exception which occured under the hood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be one of several reasons for this. Check the following:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010general/thread/d96eaefb-d519-4aef-bbe6-8afb19a4e835

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/925425

If you look at the error message, it mentions creation of new Wiki page... try deleting it?

Comment: That's the document library.. I tried doing that... Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility.CreateNewWikiPage(SPList wikiList, String url) +109

Comment: but I can't deleted anything.

Comment: Obvious question, but do you have a back-up? :/

Comment: Are you logged in as farm admin? If not, try that when deleting page from page collection

Comment: Yes, I am an owner in SharePoint as well as where the db is located at.

Comment: Yes, I am.. I tried doing that, but I get an error. See above ^^

Comment: Afraid not, short of reverting to a back up. I would post this on http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com - you will probably get more help over there :)

Comment: I'm grateful for you helping me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you look at EACH sub site's recycling bin! Also, even it may look like you're running on SQL FULL, you might not be.